# Deleting the entity with cascade in bidirectional onetomany relation does not delete the associations of the referenced entity

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am using doctrine 2.0 with the Zend framework. I have the following two entities that share bidirectional onetomany relation between them.

Bugs Table

```
/**
 * Bugs
 *
 * @Table(name="bugs")
 * @Entity
 */
class Bugs
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="reportedBugs",cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="reporter_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $reporter;

    public function setReporter($reporter)
    {
        $reporter->addReportedBug($this);
        $this->reporter = $reporter;
    }
```

Users Table

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Entity
 */
class Users
{

     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Bugs", mappedBy="reporter",cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @var Bugs[]
     **/

    private $reportedBugs = null;

    public function addReportedBug($bug)
    {
        $this->reportedBugs[] = $bug;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reportedBugs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

}
```

You can see that cascade = {"remove"} is there in both the sides of relation.

Case1:
Now if I remove an entity from the inverse side (Users), all the associated bugs that refer to this user get deleted from the "bugs" table. This is the expected behavior.

Case2:
Now if I remove an entity from the owning side(Bugs), the referred User entity is removed from the "users" table, but then it does not cascade this delete to the associated entities of this user entity in the "bugs" table. I mean just like the case 1 all the associated bugs in the "bugs" table should have been removed when a user entity is being removed. Is this an expected outcome?

Comment: Have I not put the question correctly. Does it need more explanation?

Comment: Why would you want to delete the user that reported the bug ?